# How to detect the class position and apply style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
      <td class="rsvp_role "> <input value="0" name="rsvp_role186[]" type="hidden"><span class="squaredFour" style="marign-top:-9px;" id="spnrsvp_Tank186"><input id="rsvp_Tank186" name="rsvp_role186[]" value="21" class="rsvpclass_186" style="margin-right:-10px;" type="checkbox"><label style=" margin-top:-3px;" for="rsvp_Tank186"></label></span></td>
      <td class="rsvp_role "> <input value="0" name="rsvp_role186[]" type="hidden"><span class="squaredFour" style="marign-top:-9px;" id="spnrsvp_Healer186"><input id="rsvp_Healer186" name="rsvp_role186[]" value="22" class="rsvpclass_186" style="margin-right:-10px;" type="checkbox"><label style=" margin-top:-3px;" for="rsvp_Healer186"></label></span></td>
      <td class="rsvp_role "> <input value="0" name="rsvp_role186[]" type="hidden"><span class="squaredFour" style="marign-top:-9px;" id="spnrsvp_Dps186"><input id="rsvp_Dps186" name="rsvp_role186[]" value="23" class="rsvpclass_186" style="margin-right:-10px;" type="checkbox"><label style=" margin-top:-3px;" for="rsvp_Dps186"></label></span></td>
      <td class="rsvp_role "> <input value="0" name="rsvp_role186[]" type="hidden"><span class="squaredFour" style="marign-top:-9px;" id="spnrsvp_Support186"><input id="rsvp_Support186" name="rsvp_role186[]" value="25" class="rsvpclass_186" style="margin-right:-10px;" type="checkbox"><label style=" margin-top:-3px;" for="rsvp_Support186"></label></span></td>
      <td class="rsvp_role "> <input value="0" name="rsvp_role186[]" type="hidden"><span class="squaredFour" style="marign-top:-9px;" id="spnrsvp_N/A186"><input id="rsvp_N/A186" name="rsvp_role186[]" value="26" class="rsvpclass_186" style="margin-right:-10px;" type="checkbox"><label style=" margin-top:-3px;" for="rsvp_N/A186"></label></span></td>
```

The above is the html source of my views.php. In above,the  is dynamically created.I want to add some css to 3nd class and rest other i don't want to change.Because all other than 3rd class is aligned properly with  and 3rd one is not properly aligned.If i apply a common style it apply to all and affecting other class also.

Is it possible to detect the 3rd class in a  or  so that i can apply some style to that particular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**`.eq(index)`**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/),

```
$('td.rsvp_role').eq(2) //since .eq() is having zero based index, 2 points 3
```

As per your new request you have to use,

```
$('tr td.rsvp_role:nth-child(3)')
```

Comment: i tried this and it is working for the first tr in the table.It is not working if the same class available in 2nd tr.How to apply for all tr in a table

Answer (score 2):

Example code  http://jsfiddle.net/dDuRh/1/

jQuery - `nth-child(3n)` and   `nth-child(3)`

```
$('td.rsvp_role:nth-child(3)').css({'color': 'red'});   // only first third item


$('td.rsvp_role:nth-child(3n)').css({'color': 'red'});  // it will effect third item continuously


$('td.rsvp_role:nth-child(3n)').addClass('newClass')
```

css

```
.rsvp_role:nth-child(2){

}
```

Comment: hey add example using `.addclass()` in your answer. It also may be useful. +1 for suggest css way.

Comment: @ShibinRagh +1 for css answer.can you create a demo in fiddle.

Comment: added jsfiddle link  please see my answer @user2681579

Comment: @ShibinRagh i tried this and it is working for the first tr in the table.It is not working if the same class available in 2nd tr.

Comment: Please show your code in jsfiddle , I will help you @user2681579

Comment: $('tr td.rsvp_role:nth-child(3)').css({'color': 'red'}); did the trick

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to attach css design with that DOM element ... you can do like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('td.rsvp_role').eq(2).css({'background-color':'#343434'});
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg83M/12/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `$('td.rsvp_role:eq(2)');`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
$('td.rsvp_role:nth-child(x)');// : x start at 1.
```

and

```
eq(x); // : x start at 0;
```

or if you want more detail let see

```
$('td.rsvp_role').each(function(i) {
if(i == x) {
}
})
```